# Split string by using CHARINDEX() in RIGHT() or SUBSTRING() return incorrect result

Tags: sql-server, charindex

I want to split a column into two. I want to select values from where cell value has `'('` So here is my requirement:
Input Strings:

```
col: mystr
----------
123(0)
233 (123)
23 (A)
2 (122)
```

Required Output:

```
Output
-------
(0)
(123)
(A)
(122)
```

I have done following:

```
 SELECT right(mystr,LEN(mystr)-
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(',mystr)=0 THEN LEN(mystr) 
 ELSE CHARINDEX('(',mystr) END 
 + 1) 
 FROM docs
```

How it works: I want to select index where I found first `'('` and then select values next to it. As `CHARINDEX()` work from Left to right. So instead of:

```
select right(mystr,CHARINDEX('(',mystr))
```

I subtracted index from total length `LEN(mystr)-CHARINDEX('(',mystr)`.

Here I found a scenario when `'('` was not found and `'CHARINDEX()'` returned `0` So in case `'('` was not found I made the whole term `0` by:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(',mystr)=0 THEN LEN(mystr) 
ELSE CHARINDEX('(',mystr) END
```

Here first element is not selected so I added `+1` to whole term but it results in an extra value:

```
mystr Out without +1,  Out with +1, Out with +1 moved inside else;  desired 
-----   ------------   -----------    -----------------             -------
 112        ''             2              ''                          ''
 1(0)       0)             (0)             )                          (0)
 1 (12)     12)            (12)            )                          (12)
```

I have also tried with `substring()` but it has same issue:

```
SELECT substring(mystr,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(',mystr)=0 THEN LEN(mystr) 
ELSE CHARINDEX('(',mystr) END,
LEN(mystr)-CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(',mystr)=0 THEN LEN(mystr) 
ELSE CHARINDEX('(',mystr)END +1) FROM docs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If open to a Table-Valued Functions, consider the following:

Tired of extacting and parsing strings (left(), right(), charindex(), ...), I modified a parse function to accept two non-like delimiters.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (mystr varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('122'),
('123(0)'),
('233 (123)'),
('23 (A)'),
('2 (122)')

Select A.*
      ,NewVal = IsNull('('+B.RetVal+')','')   -- Adding back the ()'s
 From  @YourTable A
 Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](A.mystr,'(',')') B
```

**Returns**

```
mystr       NewVal
122 
123(0)      (0)
233 (123)   (123)
23 (A)      (A)
2 (122)     (122)
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: Though tough but does work. Would be better for everyone if you explain function a little bit

Comment: @abdulqayyum I'll add some comments in a bit, but I use this function for a variety reasons like parsing HTML, JSON (pre 2016), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(20) = '123(A)';
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(', @x) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE RIGHT(@x, LEN(@x) - CHARINDEX('(', @x) + 1) END AS x
```

Comment: Oh thanks, basically I did moved `+1` inside `case` statement, but not inside `CHARINDEX()`

Comment: It is not inside charindex. ;-) It is inside the "RIGHT()" part od the statement. You want to get 1 char more than length - charindex. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have nothing after the last `)`, so you just can use some large number to point how many symbols to get:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(   
    [value] VARCHAR(48)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES ('123(0)')
      ,('233 (123)')
      ,('23 (A)')
      ,('2 (122)');

SELECT CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX('(', [value]) <> 0 THEN SUBSTRING([value], CHARINDEX('(', [value]), 100) ELSE '' END
FROM @DataSource;
```

If there are values after the final `)`:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(   
    [value] VARCHAR(48)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES ('123(0) test')
      ,('233 (123) test 12')
      ,('23 (A)')
      ,('2 (122) sometthing');

SELECT SUBSTRING([value], CHARINDEX('(', [value]),  CHARINDEX(')', [value]) - CHARINDEX('(', [value]) + 1)
FROM @DataSource;
```